# When restart Loader it creates new thread every time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

When I call `restartLoader` it creates new thread every time. Guess the reason is that my `AsincTaskLoader` is static & Fragment is static too, isn't it? What should I do to use just one thread to reload my data? Thanx

```
public static class NewsBelarusSectionFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object> {
    …
            @Override
            public Loader<Object> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
                   return new FeedsAsyncTaskLoader(getActivity());
            }

            public static class FeedsAsyncTaskLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Object> {
            …
```

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTasks use regular Threads in background to do the job Asynchronously, is a rule of Threads that once they're done, the Thread dies and cannot be reused/started again, hence based on that Java Core Behavior Threads cannot be reused to do a functionality they already performed, once the "run" method is over the thread is gone forever, if you need the same thread to reload data, you need to come up with your own thread and mechanism to put it on hold until the next set of data have to be loaded and keep it in a loop, which i won't recommend because its quiet expensive in performance and you would have to take care of all the resources release, if you need the Loader to do its job in the very same Thread each time, chances that you are doing something wrong are high...

Regards!

Comment: Thanks, I means if I create a new thread every time to load my data to ListView it's ok & I shoildn't care about threads? I had run the App in debug mode and that threands shown as Running, and I guess it means that they are still working and not suspended.